# Group and join two tables based on id?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table that looks something like this:

```
id | name
---+-------
1  |  cola
2  |  pepsi
3  |  sprite
```

and another table:

```
customer | buy1 | buy2
---------+------+-----
Jhon     | 2    | 3
Alice    | 1    | 3
Tony     | 3    | 2
```

I want to join the two tables and generate

```
customer | buy1  | buy2
---------+-------+--------
Jhon     | Pepsi | Sprite
Alice    | Cola  | Sprite
Tony     | Sprite| Pepsi
```

Comment: Note that enumerated column names are sometimes indicative of poor schema design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT C.customer, REF.NAME, REF2.NAME
 FROM OTHER_TABLE AS C
 JOIN TABLE_SOMETHING_LIKE_THIS AS REF ON C.BUY1 = REF.ID
 JOIN TABLE_SOMETHING_LIKE_THIS AS REF2 ON C.BUY2 = REF2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write subqueries in a select list like this:

```
select 
    customer,
    (select name from tbl1 where id = buy1) buy1,
    (select name from tbl1 where id = buy2) buy2
from 
    tbl2;
```